# Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Please help me to know , Is there any option in the azure service fabric to delay deprovision ? I have a micro service application hosted in fabric which is distributed in different nodes at their instances . If i tried to disengage/deprovision the service from portal , Can the service fabric internally check whether any transaction is going any of the instances or not , If it is engaged , Will it wait for complete it ? Also want to know , If microsoft is not providing such a service , does we have any powershell command to check the instance status ?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to tyadams answer, we find it useful to copy the reference to the cancellationToken given to the RunAsync method and use this in all our async methods.  So at least we can gracefully shutdown any activities when the fabric shuts down the service.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "disengage/deprovision the service from portal" you are referring to deleting the service via the Service Fabric Explorer web app (perhaps via a link followed from the portal).  Please correct me if this is wrong.

To answer your question directly, the framework will not wait for in-flight operations to complete during a service delete.  Every replica for the service will lose its read and write permissions, causing all in-flight operations to fail. We do not offer a way to stall during this step in order to, for example, allow currently open transactions to be completed.

The reason we do not offer this semantic, is that service deletion is expected to be rare or permanent, and that delaying deletion for the final operation doesn't enable any additional scenarios.  In either case, if a client is attempting operations on a service being deleted, either:

1. The last client operation may fail due to delete racing and revoking read/write permissions
2. Every subsequent client operation will fail due to the service no longer existing

or

1. The last client operation will succeed due to deletion being delayed
2. Every subsequent client operation will fail due to the service no longer existing

The expectation is that any client or dependent service should have already been updated or deleted prior to deleting the service they depend on, as you are making the permanent decision that this service should no longer exist.